# Change of page width in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make the div width change after clicking the button. The problem is that the width will change while the page does not behave as if it was viewed, for example, on a phone in this width. I would like to achieve such an effect as, for example, in Google Chrome by clicking on toggle device toolbar. I am trying with:

```
$('.my-btn').on('click', function()
    {
        $('#content').width('575px');
    });
```

Comment: Your question seems to be too unclear for people to help.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve smooth transition?

Comment: Is this the only style attribute applied to your div?  Perhaps you could show us the div you are modifying.

Comment: Please read [ask]

Comment: It seems to work just fine here:  http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/301621/

Answer (score 0):

Your question has not enough details.
But I think what you're looking for is:

```
$('.my-btn').click(function(e) {
    $('#content').animate({
        'width': 575+'px'
    }, 500);
});
```